# Lie derivative and partial derivative commute when applied to metric?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, lie-derivative

I am currently trying to find an expression for the Lagrangian variation of the Christoffel symbols $\Delta \Gamma^\lambda {}_{\mu\nu}$. For the Eulerian variation $\delta \Gamma^\lambda {}_{\mu\nu}$ everything is a lot simpler since the Eulerian variation $\delta$ commutes with the partial derivative $\partial$; but the Lagrangian variation $\Delta = \delta + \mathcal{L}_\xi$ (where $\xi$ is the Lagrangian displacement, i.e. some arbitrary vector field) does not obey such simple commutation relations.

My hope is that the expression for the Lagrangian variation of the Christoffel symbol is
$$
\Delta \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu\kappa} 
\left(
    \nabla_\lambda \Delta g_{\kappa\nu} 
    + \nabla_\nu \Delta g_{\kappa\lambda} 
    - \nabla_\kappa \Delta g_{\nu\lambda}
\right),
$$
where $\Delta g_{\mu\nu}$ is the Lagrangian variation of the metric.

I can derive this expression if I could show that
$$
\partial_\lambda \mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\mu\nu} = \mathcal{L}_\xi \partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}. \qquad (1)
$$
But $\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}$ is not a tensorial quantity, so I'm not sure how to calculate the Lie derivative of it. If I pretend that these are the components of a tensor and write down the expression for the Lie derivative (right-hand side of (1)), I end up with the additional terms $(\partial_\lambda \partial_\mu \xi^\sigma) g_{\sigma\nu} + (\partial_\lambda \partial_\nu \xi^\sigma) g_{\mu\sigma}$; I believe they appear only because I wrongly use the tensor formula for $\mathcal{L}_\xi$ when applying it to non-tensor objects.

Is (1) correct and if so, how could this be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine gave me the hint, that is as crucial as it is simple, on how to calculate
$$
  \mathcal{L}_\xi \partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}.
$$
Express the partial derivative using the covariant derivative (with the handy fact that the metric is compatible) plus some terms including the Christoffel symbols, i.e.
$$
\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_\lambda g_{\mu\nu} + \Gamma^\sigma {}_{\mu\lambda} g_{\sigma\nu} + \Gamma^\sigma {}_{\nu\lambda} g_{\mu\sigma}.
$$
After using the Leibniz-rule on the Lie derivative, one also needs an expression for the Lie derivative of Christoffel symbols but this can be found [also here on SE-Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415759/lie-derivative-of-the-christoffel-symbol), and we have
$$
  \mathcal{L}_\xi \Gamma^\mu {}_{\nu\lambda} = \xi^\sigma R^\mu {}_{\lambda\sigma\nu}
      + \nabla_\nu \nabla_\lambda \xi^\mu.
$$
Using these relations and the properties of the Riemann tensor, it takes only a few lines of algebraic reformulations to arrive at Eq. (1):
$$
\mathcal{L}_\xi \partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\lambda \mathcal{L}_\xi g_{\mu\nu}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\partial_{\lambda}g_{\mu\nu}$ in fact a Lie derivative: indeed, for functions, the Lie derivative in the direction of a vector field and the action of the vector field itself coincide, so that
\begin{align}
\partial_{\lambda}g_{\mu\nu} &= \partial_{\lambda}(g(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}))\\
&= \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\lambda}}(g(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu})) \\
&= (\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\lambda}}g)(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}) + g([\partial_{\lambda},\partial_{\mu}],\partial_{\nu}) + g(\partial_{\mu},[\partial_{\lambda},\partial_{\nu}])\\
&= (\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\lambda}}g)(\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}),
\end{align}
where the last equality comes from the fact that for a coordinates system, $[\partial_{\lambda},\partial_{\nu}]=0$.

Now, recall that $\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\xi}}\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\lambda}} = \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\lambda}}\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\xi}}$ because for any two vector fields, $\mathcal{L}_X\mathcal{L}_Y - \mathcal{L}_Y\mathcal{L}_X = \mathcal{L}_{[X,Y]}$.
The result follows immediately.

Comment: thanks for this, but some things are unclear to me: a) How did you get the second equality? Because $g(\partial_\mu, \partial_\nu)$ is a simple function and then directional derivative and Lie derivative coincide? b) If you can show that $\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}$ is a tensorial quantity, then also the Christoffel symbols should be a tensorial quantity, but they're not. c) With your proof, I can show that any partial derivative of any tensor is a tensor; where does it go wrong?

Comment: @mangrove84
a) You're right, it relies on the fact that Lie derivative acts on functions as vector fields.b) and c) I removed all reference to tensoriality to avoid confusion. You're right saying that this is not a tensor on the whole manifold, but there is an interpretation of it as a tensor on the domain of the coordinates system (as well as for Christoffel symbols). But this is not the point there.

Comment: @mangrove84 Hopefully, this still answers your original question

Comment: I'm still trying to understand $\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\xi}}\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\lambda}} = \mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\lambda}}\mathcal{L}_{\partial_{\xi}}$ since in fact $\xi$ is my (random) Lagrangian displacement and not a coordinate derivative, i.e. I don't expect $[\partial_\lambda, \xi]$ to vanish.

Comment: @mangrove84 Could you elaborate on what you call a *random Langrangian displacement*? I'm not a physicist (and lots of people there aren't) so it might be valuable to give details on its construction

Comment: The Lagrangian displacement, in my case, traces the location of a fluid element when it is moved away from its equilibrium. By "random" I wanted to say that $\xi$ could be any vector, it is not necessarily parallel to any of the coordinates.

Comment: @mangrove84 So, basically, $\xi$ can be any vector field on $M$ right?

Comment: Yes, $\xi$ could be any vector field.
PS: I'm trying to address you via the "@" sign, but this always gets removed from my comment.

Comment: @mangrove84 Great, then I'll try to think about it and come back to you later. Regarding the "@": this is because you are replying on my answer where only the two of us posted comments, and there is no ambiguity. If a third person were to intervene, then there will be no auto-deletion of this "@" sign. However, I can reply to you with this sign because I could be commenting my own answer and not replying to your comment (I think)