# Lie derivative of connection in Maple

Tags: differential-geometry

Maple's documentation says that the  Lie derivative of a connection $\nabla_Y(Z)$ is the type (1, 2) tensor field
$S = {\mathcal L}_X \nabla$
that is  defined (when viewed as mapping from pairs of vector fields to vector fields) by
$$
({\mathcal L}_X \nabla)(Y,Z) {=} {\mathcal L}_X(\nabla_YZ ) - \nabla_{{\mathcal L}_X Y}(Z) - \nabla_X ({\mathcal L}_Y Z).
$$

Based on the answer to [Details to Lie derivative of Christoffel symbols](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4643495/details-to-lie-derivative-of-christoffel-symbols)
I would have expected
$$
({\mathcal L}_X \nabla)(Y,Z) = {\mathcal L}_X(\nabla_YZ) - \nabla_{{\mathcal L}_X Y}(Z) - \nabla_Y ({\mathcal L}_X Z).
$$
Is the Maple documentation wrong or is there some identity that says the last terms of each expression are  are equal?

Comment: Note that the left-hand side is $C^\infty$-linear in $X$, and so the right-hand side must be as well. Is that true of what you would have expected?

Comment: @TedShifrin The left hand side is not tensorial in $X$, only in $Y$ and $Z$. $L_XT$ is rarely tensorial in $X$ even for tensors $T$

Comment: @Didier A sloppy error on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: the posted link is right, Maple is wrong.

---

Long answer: there is a way to determine which of the two proposed formulas cannot be the right answer.
If $\mathcal{L}_X\nabla$ is a tensor, then it must be $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$-linear in its entries, and in particular in $Z$.
So, let's take $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ three vector fields, and $f$ a smooth function.
We compute:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_X(\nabla_Y(fZ))
&= \mathcal{L}_X((Yf)Z + f\nabla_YZ) \\
&= (X(Yf))Z + (Yf)\mathcal{L}_XZ + (Xf)\nabla_YZ + f\mathcal{L}_X(\nabla_YZ),
\label{eq:1} \tag{1} \\
\\
\nabla_{\mathcal{L}_XY}(fZ)
&= ((\mathcal{L}_XY)f)Z + f \nabla_{\mathcal{L}_XY}Z,
\label{eq:2} \tag{2} \\
\\
\nabla_X(\mathcal{L}_Y(fZ))
&= \nabla_X((Yf)Z + f\mathcal{L}_YZ) \\
&= X(Yf)Z + (Yf)\nabla_XZ + (Xf)\mathcal{L}_YZ + f\nabla_X(\mathcal{L}_YZ),
\label{eq:3} \tag{3} \\
\\
\nabla_Y(\mathcal{L}_X(fZ))
&= \nabla_Y((Xf)Z +f \mathcal{L}_XZ) \\
&= (Y(Xf))Z + (Xf)\nabla_YZ + (Yf)\mathcal{L}_XZ + f\nabla_Y(\mathcal{L}_XZ).
\label{eq:3'} \tag{3'}
\end{align}
Since $(\mathcal{L}_XY)f = X(Yf) - Y(Xf)$, then
$$
\eqref{eq:1}-\eqref{eq:2}-\eqref{eq:3'} = f\mathcal{L}_X(\nabla_YZ) -f\nabla_{\mathcal{L}_XY}Z - f\nabla_Y(\mathcal{L}_XZ),
$$
while
\begin{align}
\eqref{eq:1} - \eqref{eq:2} - \eqref{eq:3}
&= -((\mathcal{L}_XY)f)Z +(Yf)(\mathcal{L}_XZ - \nabla_XZ) + (Xf)(\nabla_YZ-\mathcal{L}_YZ)\\
&\quad + f \mathcal{L}_X(\nabla_YZ) -f\nabla_{\mathcal{L}_XY}Z -f\nabla_X(\mathcal{L}_YZ).
\end{align}
It is clear that $\eqref{eq:1} - \eqref{eq:2} - \eqref{eq:3'}$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$-linear while $\eqref{eq:1} - \eqref{eq:2} - \eqref{eq:3}$ is not.

Comment: @Didier Thanks! I wonder if Maple actually implemented wrongly?  I don't have access to Maple, but was just looking for  info about ${\mathcal L}_X\nabla$. Curiously $({\mathcal L_X}\nabla)(Y,Z)$ seems to be symmetric in  $Y$, $Z$ even if $\nabla$ is not torsion free....

Comment: @Didier. That was a typo. I meant $Y$ and $Z$ -- as if $\delta \Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric in $\mu$ and $\nu$ even when $\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}$ is not.

Comment: @mikestone Hum, not sure about it. Let me think about it, I'll came back with my insight

Comment: @Didier Thanks!  I find $[ ({\mathcal L}_X \nabla)(Y, Z)]^\alpha=Z^\mu Y^\nu \Big(X^\rho \partial_\rho \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu} - (\partial_\sigma X^\alpha) \Gamma^\sigma_{\mu\nu} + (\partial_\nu X^\sigma) \Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\sigma} + (\partial_\mu X^\sigma) \Gamma^\alpha_{\sigma\nu}+\partial^2_{\mu\nu}X^\alpha\Big)$ which is symmetric in $\mu\nu$

Comment: @Didier. Ah  only if  the $X^\rho \partial \rho \Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}$ is. So not a mystery. Sorry!